# Ionic 4 modify css padding rule of item-native class

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I need to modify the padding of an *item-native* class element that is inside the *#shadow-root* but I am unable to do so.

[image]

I've tried many kinds of rules, but none of them work:

```
--padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
padding-left:0px !important;
```

In these selectors:

```
.item-native {...}

ion-item .item-native {...}

ion-item {
  .item-native {...}
}
```

I've checked that the rule which is setting the padding is the *padding-inline-start*.

[image]

I've read that the only way to modify css in shadow-root elements is doing it through css4 but in my case I suppose I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

My goal is to do it only in a scss file because I don't want to modify the padding rule in the hole project.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the padding just adding the class "ion-no-padding" to the ion-item element in the HTML:

```
<ion-item class="ion-no-padding">
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying in many ways the solution was in modifying the next rules:

```
--padding-start:0px;
--ion-safe-area-left: 0px;
```